# Sort vector of object pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, object, vector

I'm creating a c++ program of a race.
I have the race class. Each race has a name, a distance and vector of results pointers(its a result for each participant).
The result class has a pointer to the participant and a time.
The class time has hours, minutes and seconds.
I want to sort the vector of results from the fastest time to the slowest, so to compare results I created the function `bool operator <(Result& res2) const` in the class `result`.

All the functions in the .h file are implemented, I'm just not showing them all.

I'm almost certain that the function `sortResults` is not right but the function `operator<` is giving me errors that I don't know how to solve. It gives me this error in all the if statements: Multiple markers at this line

```
- passing 'const Time' as 'this' argument of 'unsigned int Time::getHours()' discards qualifiers [-
 fpermissive]
- Line breakpoint: race.cpp [line: 217]
- Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: unsigned int getHours() '
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

.h file:

```
class Time
{
    unsigned int hours;
    unsigned int minutes;
    unsigned int seconds;
public:
    Time(unsigned int h, unsigned int m, unsigned int s, unsigned int ms);
    Time();
    unsigned int gethours();
    unsigned int getMinuts();
    unsigned int getSeconds();
    string show();
};

class Participant {
    string name;
    unsigned int age;
    string country;
public:
    Participant(string n, unsigned int a, string c);
    string getName();
    string getCountry();
    int getAge();
    string show() const;
};

class Result {
    Participant *part;
    Time time;
public:
    Result(Participant  *p, Time t);
    Participant *getParticipant() const;
    Time getTime();
    string show();
    bool operator <(Result& res2) const;
};

class Race {
    string name;
    float distance;
    vector<Result *> results;
public:
    Race(string nm, float dist);
    string getName();
    void setName(string nm);
    float getDistance();
    vector<Result *> sortResults();
    void addResult(Result *r);
    string showRaceResults();
    string show();
};
```

.cpp file:

```
bool Result::operator <(Result& res2) const {
    if (time.gethours() < res2.getTime().gethours())
        return true;
    else {
        if (time.gethours() > res2.getTime().gethours())
            return false;
        else {
            if (time.getMinutes() < res2.getTime().getMinutes())
                return true;
            else {
                if (time.getMinutes() > res2.getTime().getMinutes())
                    return false;
                else {
                    if (time.getSeconds() < res2.getTime().getSeconds())
                        return true;
                    else {
                            return false;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

vector<Result *> Race::sortResults() {
    sort (results.begin(), results.end(), operator <);
return results;
}
```

Comment: Please, oh please get rid of all the `else` cruft in the `operator<`. Your function will look much nicer.

Comment: Like `bool Result::operator <(Result& rhs) const { return std::make_tuple(time.gethours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds()) < std::make_tuple(rhs.time.gethours(), rhs.time.getMinutes(), rhs.time.getSeconds()); };`

Comment: Is it right to use an operator to sort a vector? Or should I create a function like: bool Result::lowerTime(Result& res1, Result& res2) const, to sort the results vector? Whats the best way?

Answer (score 3):

You should declare and define `Time::gethours()` as constant member function.

```
class Time {
// ...
    unsigned int gethours() const;  // note the "const"
};

unsigned int Time::gethours() const { /* ... */ } // note the "const"
```

To sort `vector<Result*>`, you need to

1. Change `Result::operator<()` to take `const Result&` rather than `Result&` as parameter
2. Define a comparison function for `Result*` which looks like `static bool cmpResultPtr(const Result* lhs, const Result* rhs) { return *lhs < *rhs; }`
3. Call `sort(results.begin(), results.end(), cmpResultPtr);`

The function `cmpResultPtr()` could be defined in the .cpp file, before the definition of `Race::sortResults()`.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the error of the operator< function. But now what should I do in the sortResults function to get it to work?

Comment: @user2880113 As long as you defined operator<, just call sort() with the first 2 parameters and skip the third one.

Comment: I created the function like: _italic_ **bold** `void Race::sortResults() {
 sort(results.begin(), results.end());
}`

Comment: But its not sorting the vector of results. Results is a vector where each element is a pointer for a result and maybe I have to change the function sortResults to deal with the pointers?

Comment: I cant get that to work. The function cmpResultPtr shoul be declared in the class Result? In the .h or in the .cpp? The sort(results.begin(), results.end(), cmpResultPtr); should be called in the .h or in the .cpp? Ive been hours and hours around this and I cant do it.

Comment: cmpResultPtr is a C function outside any class. Call sort inside sortResults().

Comment: Where exactly should I put the function cmpResultPtr(const Resultado* lhs, const Resultado* rhs) { return *lhs < *rhs;} ? If I put it in the .h or .cpp or in the main it allways gives me "Syntax error"!

Comment: @user2880113 Updated. Please update question about the "Syntax error" message. Also your class is named `Result` rather than `Resultado`.

Answer (score 1):

You declare operator< to be const but Time::getHours, which it calls, doesn't have the same declaration. To the compiler, this means getHours could change the value of the time member which violates the constness of operator<.